# Java. IO. Как на разных ОС реализуется интерфейс Path

Tags: java, файлы, io, path

Я использую в своем коде интерфейс Path, но я так понимаю что есть специфика при работе с UNIX и Windows, но я никак не могу понять ограничивается ли это началом в абсолютных путях и обратными слэшами с экранированием или нет? В общем как мне использовать объекты Path так, что-бы это работало везде одинаково.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path` имеет несколько реализаций под определенный файловые системы.

Формат записи пути к файлу отличается, и то что будет работать в `windows` не обязательно будет работать в `linux` или какой то другой ос. Чтобы максимально сгладить эту проблему, в [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) прописан способ указания путей.

> Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logs", "access.log");
>
> BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Так же есть способ с использованием разделителя, который зависит от текущей файловой системы.

```
String path = "dir" + File.pathSeparator + "file.txt";
```

Comment: Да я тоже видел этот пример в доках Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logs", "access.log"); но не понял синтаксис аргументов. Так-то вроде понятно что logs это папка, а access.log это имя файла. НО в итоге то какой разделитель использовать если у меня ("/a/b/c/logs","/a/b/c/logs/access.log") ??? как применить этот кейс не понятно???

Comment: В этом то и фишка, что туда можно передать произвольное количество строк, которые будут разделяться между собой символом. А этот символ уже определяется в зависимости от файловой системы.

Comment: В вашем примере будет что то вроде .getPath("a","b","c","logs","access.log")